# distinct primes dividing norm of ideal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field. Let $I$ be an integral ideal of $O_K$ such that $pq \mid N(I)$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Prove that $I$ is not a prime ideal.

I am unsure of how to complete this problem. I let $N(I) = pqr$. Hence we have that $<N(I)> = <pqr>$ and we also have that $I \mid N(I) = <pqr>$ but I am not sure what to do after this. I also don't see any way that I can use the property $N(AB) = N(A)N(B)$ because I am doing a proof by contradiction and assuming that $I$ is prime. Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Why is $p\not\mid r$ and $q\not\mid r$?

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have added that.

Comment: I agree with the duplicate target @markvs found. As per the dupehammer rules, my vote will be immediately binding. Commenting mostly so that you can at-ping me also, if there is something I overlooked. From the point of view of your approach it may be better to look at the sum ideal $I+\langle p\rangle$. But this is relatively basic property of prime ideals. The exercise does make sense within a narrow time window while developing the theory. Which is why A) it is difficult to give the answer that matches exactly with what you know at this time and why B) I want to comment.

Comment: The point of Dietrich's answer in the duplicate thread is that if $I$ were a prime ideal then $\mathcal{O}/I$ would be an integral domain with $N(I)$ elements. But a finite integral domain is a field etc.